# Normal Mode Analysis - Which theorem states "Bounded domain implies complete orthonormal basis"?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, stability-theory

I am reading about normal mode analysis - the idea that perturbations from a steady state can be expanded as a Fourier Series if the domain is bounded, or as a Fourier transform integral in the case the domain is unbounded.

What is the name of the theorem which states that if your domain $\mathcal{D}$ is bounded, then the superposition of normal modes spans the space of functions the perturbation lies in?

In other words, which theorem states *boundedness of domain $\Rightarrow$ completeness?*

Comment: There is no such theorem unless you define the space of functions the perturbation lies in. If you do not define that space correctly, then there will be functions that cannot be obtained as a superposition of normal modes.

Comment: Ah I see yes, thank you - I should have been more specific. The functions I am working with are $L^{2}$